# Android 2.3 Custom notification keep giving android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification posted from package: Couldn't expand RemoteViews

Tags: android, notifications

I trying to show a custom notification in Android 2.3 with no clickable items.

This is my XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/icon" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearlayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/image"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            style="@style/NotificationTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="This is event name" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            style="@style/NotificationText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="by Name Name" />
    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my code:

```
public void show(PicoEvent event)
{
    Notification notification = new Notification();
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(getClass().getPackage().getName(), R.layout.notification);
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);     
    contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.title, event.getName());
    contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.text, event.getPlace());       
    notification.when = 0;
    notification.tickerText = "New Event is now starting";
    notification.icon = R.drawable.icon;        
    notification.contentIntent = contentIntent;
    notification.contentView = contentView;
    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
}
```

And yet i always get the exception logcat:

```
09-04 12:15:26.140: E/AndroidRuntime(13350): android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification posted from package com.coapps.pico: Couldn't expand RemoteViews for: StatusBarNotification(package=com.coapps.pico id=0 tag=null notification=Notification(vibrate=null,sound=null,defaults=0x0,flags=0x0))
09-04 12:15:26.140: E/AndroidRuntime(13350):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1048)
09-04 12:15:26.140: E/AndroidRuntime(13350):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-04 12:15:26.140: E/AndroidRuntime(13350):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
09-04 12:15:26.140: E/AndroidRuntime(13350):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
09-04 12:15:26.140: E/AndroidRuntime(13350):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-04 12:15:26.140: E/AndroidRuntime(13350):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
09-04 12:15:26.140: E/AndroidRuntime(13350):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
09-04 12:15:26.140: E/AndroidRuntime(13350):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)
09-04 12:15:26.140: E/AndroidRuntime(13350):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: issue with the remoteview package name

Comment: ok.. how get i solve it ?

Comment: ohhhh i did solve it....
How did you found out the package name was the problem ?

Comment: Hi Asaf, my custom notification works fine on all androids 3 and above, but I'm getting the same error like you just on my tablet 4.1. Can you tell me please how you actually solved it?

Comment: I actually dont remember the specific question but usually it happens when using a clickable layout like image button or anything like it